# How large do algebraic representations need to be for packing circles in squares?

Tags: circle-packing, algebraic-complexity

(This question is inspired by [Erich's Packing Center](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/).

I'm just asking about circles in squares to keep things simple, since I suspect

any answer would apply just-as-well to the rest of the problems on that page.)

Define $\: \hspace{.04 in}f : \{\hspace{-0.04 in}1,\hspace{-0.03 in}2\hspace{.02 in},\hspace{-0.04 in}3,\hspace{-0.04 in}4,\hspace{-0.04 in}5,...\hspace{-0.04 in}\} \to [0,\hspace{-0.04 in}\scriptsize+\normalsize \infty \hspace{-0.02 in}) \;$ by letting $\hspace{.04 in}f(n)$ be the side length of the smallest square that

$n$ unit circles can be packed inside. $\;\;\;$ (The existence of a minimum follows from compactness.)

> In terms of $n$, what upper bounds are known on the size of algebraic representations of $\hspace{.04 in}f(n)$?

I imagine that "algebraic representations" would mean with

$\;$ the constant $-1$

$\;\;\;\;$ and
$\;$ the binary operations plus and times

$\;\;\;\;$ and
$\;$ extracting a root from a single-variable polynomial given

$\;$ its coefficient-vector and an interval that brackets the root

.

**The Only Upper Bound I Know:**

For each $n$, $\hspace{.04 in}f(n)$ is the smallest value of the unique free variable in a $\Theta(n)$-variable

[existential formula over the reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_theory_of_the_reals) with $\Theta(n)$ other symbols that satisfies the formula.

Since [the quantifiers can be eliminated from such a formula in $n^{O(n)}$ time](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0747717110800057/1-s2.0-S0747717110800057-main.pdf?_tid=f13b56b0-d065-11e4-b9a5-00000aab0f27&acdnat=1427009878_afe841b1f48690ae12e613d86c5d458c) and the operations plus and times are continuous, $\hspace{.04 in}f(n)$ is a solution to a univariate equation of length $n^{O(n)}$ in the first-order theory

of the reals that does not hold identically. $\:$ With some work (to see that size doesn't blow up), one can

see that such equations are equivalent to standard-form single-variable integer-coefficient polynomial equations of length $n^{O(n)}$ that do not hold identically. $\:$ By [Theorem 1.2](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/pap/rootBounds/Batra-JSC-Submit-April21.pdf) (or any root separation bound

that's not much worse), $\hspace{.04 in}f(n)$ can be bracketed by an interval whose endpoints are rationals with $n^{O(n)}\hspace{-0.02 in}$-bit denominators. $\;\;\;$ Since $\: 0\leq \hspace{.02 in}f(n) \leq poly(n) \:$ holds for all $n$, those rationals can be chosen so that additionally their numerators are $n^{O(n)}$ bits long. $\;\;\;$ Thus, $\hspace{.04 in}f(n)$ can be given by a rational interval that brackets a root of an integer-coefficient polynomial such that the total size of that representation is $n^{O(n)}$.

> Is anything better known?

${}$

Comment: You're citing slightly outdated complexity results for quantifier elimination; they were improved by Basu-Pollack-Roy, cf e.g. http://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/marie-francoise.roy/bpr-ed2-posted1.html 
I don't know whether this improves your bound (perhaps it does, to something like $p(n)2^{O(n)}$, for $p$ a polynomial).

Comment: I'm looking at Exercise 11.9 from the  "For downloading the .pdf file of the book" link on the page you linked to, and as far as I can see, that will only improve on the result I cited when $\ell$ is $(\Omega(1))^k$ (using the notation of Algorithm 11.16). $\;$

Comment: Could you explain how the formula you are eliminating from looks like? E.g. for optimisation they have Sect. 14.2 which might give a better bound...

Comment: Essentially, "there are $\:2\cdot n\:$ reals such that the $n$ points described by those reals are each at most $\:r+1\:$ from the origin and at least $2$ from each other". $\;\;\;$ Thus, $s$ would be quadratic in $n$. $\:$ Do you know where they address the sizes of the coefficients produced by their global optimization algorithm? $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: If there is a bound on the bit-lengths of the coefficients that is better than $n^{O(n)}$, then that would yield a better bound for my problem (in particular, enough for the bounty), since it would provide an explicit constant for the main factor of the runtime. $\:$ (i.e., $n^{\hspace{.02 in}O(n)}$ becomes $\: n^{\hspace{.02 in}c\cdot n} \cdot \text{something_asymptotically_smaller_than_that} \;$.) $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: I mean "at most $\:r-1\:$ from the origin" instead of $\:r+1\;$. $\;\;\;$ I believe the rest of my two previous comments are correct.) $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: It seems that the formula in question has too many quadratic inequalities, $O(n^2)$, to hope for an improvement of the bound (well, even $O(n)$ is too much...).